# Work on 1 line at a time in parallel

Tags: r, foreach, domc

I am reading in a large file one line at a time. What I would like to do to speed everything up is to work on multiple lines in parallel. But the way I am doing it right now is not working. I have never tried this so I am not really sure how it works.

[testdata.csv](http://sdrv.ms/1gsyGlo)

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel) #or with doMC



read.block <- function(ifile, lines, block, readFunc=read.csv,
                   skip=(lines*(block-1))+ifelse((header) & (block>1) & (!inherits(ifile, "connection")),1,0),
                   nrows=lines,header=TRUE,sep="\t",...){
  if(block > 1){
    colnms<-NULL
    if(header)
    {
      colnams <- unlist(readFunc(ifile, nrows=1, header=FALSE, sep=sep, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
      #print(colnams)
    }
    p = readFunc(ifile, skip = skip, nrows = nrows, header=FALSE, sep=sep,...)
    if(! is.null(colnams))
    {
      colnames(p) = colnams
    }
  } else {
    p = readFunc(ifile, skip = skip, nrows = nrows, header=header, sep=sep)
  }
  return(p)
}

mendl.error <- matrix(, nrow=15, ncol=9)

foreach(i=1:15)%dopar%{
  ifile.c <- file("testdata.csv", open = "r") #open file connection to read
  ifile.valid <- read.block(ifile.c, lines=1, block=i) #read 1 line
  close(ifile.c) 
#do some other operations on the line which will be saved into a matrix
  mendl.error[1,] <- ifile.valid
}
```

Comment: Is the problem speed?.. because I can think of a lot of other simpler (and possibly more likely to work) ways to speed things up...

Comment: Yes. But keep in mind this is just an excerpt of a large script.

Comment: This reads like C code … which is not a good thing, because R isn’t like C at all.

Answer (score 2):

You haven’t specified what “doesn’t work” means but I’m going on a limb and say that it doesn’t speed up as expected (although I’m also not quite clear about the semantics of what you’re attempting to do).

The reason for this is that your code is not compute bound, it’s IO bound. Meaning, it has to wait for data from secondary storage. The bus for that data isn’t parallel, so all your data read requests are getting serialised. You cannot speed this up significantly by using parallelism in the fashion you’re attempting to.

In fact, your code is probably sped up if you do the reading in one go and rely on R to do the right thing. IF you really need raw reading performance here you probably need to resort to memory-mapped files. A quick Google search has turned up the [R package `bigmemory`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) which implements this.

Comment: Worth noting that the OP can use `Rprof` to verify that he's I/O-bound.

Comment: maybe `fread` too in the `data.table` package.. but not that above.

Comment: I am using next to jump to the next itteration of the loop which gives me (sorry for not mentioning this): `Error in { : 
  task 11 failed - "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level"
Calls: %dopar% -> <Anonymous>`

Comment: @crysis405 Well `next` is a language construct which only works in `for` loops. `foreach` looks like a loop but in reality it’s a function call which executes the expression you provide (via `%dopar%`, which is also a function). You can try using `return` instead of `next`. But that won’t solve the code’s problem, as alluded to in my answer.

Comment: Now I'm getting another error which I don't know whats causing it: `Error in { : task 11 failed - "object 'parent.ifile.valid' not found"
Calls: %dopar% -> <Anonymous>
` This probably doesn't mean much without the code

Comment: I think I'm still unsure how this works. What my script does is that it reads 1 line from a file connection, works on that line and then writes it to another file with `file(...,open="at")`. What I want to achieve is working on lets say 100 lines in parallel. Is that possible?

Comment: @crysis405 No don't try this. It's like me ordering a meal and it being brought to me a grain of rice at a time by 2000 waiters on 100000s of plates-- a big mess.